# Sorting inner query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, subquery

I have a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT COLA,
               COLB,
               COLC,
               COLD,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLA) AS ROWNUMBER
        FROM   TABLEXYZ)AS Tab1
WHERE  ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER  BY COLA
```

This query works fine if it has to be sorted on basis of COLA but there are problems if I attempt to sort on a basis of COLB,COLC etc.The sorting does not work.
I want to sort the inner table but the order by clause does not work and thus my sorted results are not accurate.

Comment: You need to clarify "does not works".  Post sample data, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Do you want, say, the first 10 items as ordered by COLA, with those 10 items then ordered by COLB? Do you know ahead of time (i.e. when you're writing the code) how you want data filtered and sorted, or must it be dynamic?

Comment: How does your query works with no `FROM`?

Comment: Lets say there are 100 records and at a time we show only 10 out of it . Now when i do a between clause on outer query and then do a sort on it it will only sort the 10 records that are the part of outer query result set. For a user who is sorting it will be incorrect as the inner query is not sorted properly.

Comment: @Lamak I fixed the original query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using TOP 100%.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 100% COLA,
           COLB,
           COLC,
           COLD,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLA) AS ROWNUMBER
           FROM TABLEXYZ
           ORDER BY COLB ASC) AS Tab1
WHERE  ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER  BY COLA
```

Comment: Did you try this?  It should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sorting should be also done in the rownumber clause of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... If the above didn't work never mind, I just tested this:

```
select * from(
select top 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by ColumnA) as ROWN, ColumnA, ColumnB
from dbo.TableXYZ) as lala
order by ColumnB
```

It works flawlessly. Honestly I don't know why your query isn't working (you didn't say so) but this achieves the exact same thing.